# Android Studio: when setting fill_parent on a "column" in a TableLayout/TableRow I get NullRef in designer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a weird behaviour in Android Studio (version 0.3.7) when working with a fragment layout (project has `android:minSdkVersion="14"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="16"`).

The graphical view to the right of the XML-editor gets a NullReferenceException when I which one of the view layout_height to "fill_parent" or "match_parent".

First, let's start with the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="#F0F0F0">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- HERE I CHANGE TO fill_parent !-->
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_blue"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/View01"
                android:layout_width="2px"
                android:layout_height="30dp" 
                android:background="#46000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Test test test"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And this looks like this in the designer:

[image]

Now, when I change one of the "columns" (doesnt matter which one) and set the layout_height to "fill_parent" or "match_parent", the designer view instead shows an exception:

[image]

This feels like a bug. Am I right?

Comment: If the renderer is giving you a NullPointerException, it's a bug. Please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug and if possible whittle down the layout to the minimum necessary to reproduce the bug. Thanks..

Comment: Added it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63287